# Ошибка: "Unexpected end of input"

Tags: javascript, html

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно решить проблему?

Вот сама ошибка:

```
Unexpected end of input
```

И код:

```js
function loadCategories() {
  let list = document.getElementById("categoryList");

  for (let i=0; i<categories.length;i++) {
    let category = categories[i];
    let li = document.createElement("li");

    li.setAttribute("class","list-group-item");
    li.setAttribute("onclick","clickedCategory(this,this.innerText);");

    li.innerText = category;

    list.appendChild(li);
  }
}
```

Comment: Конкретно в этом куске кода нет проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в этом куске кода нет проблем. Но вот общая информация об ошибке:

Ошибка означает, что код закончился, в то время как парсер ожидает больше кода.  **Причина**: несовпадение количества открывающих и закрывающих фигурных скобок.

**Почти всегда** речь идет об отсутствующей закрывающей фигурной скобке `}` для закрытия предшествующих блоков кода. Это говорит о том, что синтаксический анализатор ожидает найти закрывающую скобку `}`, но на самом деле достиг конца файла.

- Используйте правильные отступы, чтобы избежать таких проблем. И вообще, в принципе, **используйте отступы и форматирование!**
- Используйте *IDE* с сопоставлением скобок, чтобы выяснить, где `}` была утеряна. Большинство *IDE* выделяют совпадающие фигурные скобки, квадратные скобки и круглые скобки. Что позволяет довольно легко проверить соответствие:

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ету информатцию