# Ошибка Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - при fetch() запросе

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, выборка

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/server', {mode:'no-cors'})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
```

На сервере `JSON`:

```
[{"body":"nikita","email":"jfk"},
{"body":"daniil","email":"jfk"},
{"body":"sergey","email":"jfk"},
{"body":"karp","email":"jfk"}]
```

Ошибка при запросе с сервера:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка: "Unexpected end of input"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1472003/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-unexpected-end-of-input)

Comment: При `mode:'no-cors'` браузер не даст прочитать ответ от сервера. Настраивайте нормально либо CORS либо проксирование с текущего домена, что бы CORS вообще не понадобился.